# Migrating on-premise applications/services to CloudHub

Tags: mule, cloudhub

We have applications/services running on Mule on-premise, now we want to migrate all of them to CloudHub, are there any specific steps/considerations/limitations that needs to be followed for the success of this migration? 
We want to keep the services as-is on the cloud as they are running on-premise.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: This question is very broad. Unless you have a specific problem, this question cannot be answered.

Comment: Thanks @Mooz for your response. I just wanted to understand at the broader level whether it would need any more steps or below mentioned are fine:   1) extracting ear from the on-premise instance and eploy it to cludhub, 2) opening the firewall ports, 3) configuring the workers, etc.   Are they any other things that I need to worry?

Comment: You will need some sort of VPN connection if you're going to access the systems you have on prem. Also, Pontus' response to your question [here](https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/58102/migrating-on-premise-applicationsservices-to-cloud.html) is quite helpful based on the information you've given. (I'm assuming that is your question).

Comment: Additionally, you will need to consider your deployment (CI/CD) process as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most important parts is that each app on Cloudhub is deployed seperately.
This means that each app will be 'isolated' in it's own container and needs to have at least 0.1 vCore.

So let's say you'll have 20 apps, make sure you have 2 vCores available minimum.

The advantage is here, that different apps can run on different runtimes.

This URL will point you in some directions in terms of HTTP connectivity:
https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/cloudhub-networking-guide

This part is important for port routing:

> Important: On the Mule worker, the CloudHub load balancer proxies port
>   :80 to :8081 for HTTP and proxies port :443 to :8082 for HTTPS. The
>   http.port value must be set to port 8081 for HTTP, and the https.port
>   value must be set to port 8082 for HTTPS. No other port numbers are
>   supported.

Of course you need to think about a lot more, eg.:
**Are you using file inbound/outbound endpoints that write to a local system?**

This is not possible because you won't have your file system, change to a cloud solution or SFTP/FTP.

**Are you connecting to on-premise systems (probably yes)?**

Figure out connectivity issues, firewall, VPC, etc.

VPC info: https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/virtual-private-cloud